# How to connect database with Tomcat server?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, rest, tomcat8

I'm doing a web service project and I want to retrieve data from a database through REST web service. But I retrieve none. Tomcat server shows this error when I try to get an output:

> can not find resource for full path: http://localhost:9090/TestWS/Service/getAllpersonsInXML
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I think it is an error in my connection. So propose me to connect server with database.

Comment: Are you getting 404 on every resource within `TestWS`? If so your web service is not deployed properly.

Comment: web service deploy correctly.it comes only when connect server with database

Comment: Okay. so my understanding is that this is your API implementation that returns *HTTP 404* when it do not have a db connection on hitting the request url `TestWS/Service/getAllpersonsInXML`. is it so?

Comment: yes.i want to retieve all data in database.so i make the database using netbeans and connect.is it right:

Comment: Can you share the implementations you have done so far?